# Admob Banner Ad not displaying in Android

Tags: android, admob

Hi I have a Android game app developed using android cocos2d i need to integrate admob i have included the following code but banner ad is not displaying please help regarding this your answers will be appreciated and it would be a great help. thank you.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private CCGLSurfaceView mGLSurfaceView;
private boolean isCreated = false;
public static FrameLayout m_rootLayout;
AdView adView;

// This is used to display Toast messages and is not necessary for your app
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (!isCreated) {
        isCreated = true;
    } else {
        return;
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try{
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(),
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()+getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()-50);

            adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "admob id");

            AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
            adView.loadAd(request);
            // Adding full screen container
            addContentView(adView, adParams);
            }catch (Exception e) {
            FlurryAgent.logEvent("ADMOB ERROR: "+e);
            }



    mGLSurfaceView = new CCGLSurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(mGLSurfaceView);


    CCDirector.sharedDirector().attachInView(mGLSurfaceView);

    getScaledCoordinate();

    Global.assetManager = getAssets();
    Global.context = this;
    Global.loadUserInfo();
    CCScene scene = CCScene.node();
    scene.addChild(new SplashScene(), -1);

    CCDirector.sharedDirector().runWithScene(scene);


    //-------------IAP-----------------------
    Log.d(TAG1, "Creating IAB helper.");
        mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
        mHelper.enableDebugLogging(true);
        Log.d(TAG1, "Starting setup.");
        mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
            public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Setup finished.");

                if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                    // Oh noes, there was a problem.
                    complain("Problem setting up in-app billing: " + result);
                    return;
                }

                // Hooray, IAB is fully set up. Now, let's get an inventory of stuff we own.
                Log.d(TAG, "Setup successful. Querying inventory.");
                mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
            }
        });


        Global.myActivity=this;
}
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.game.puzzlegame"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.game.puzzlegame.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.revmob.ads.fullscreen.FullscreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" >
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: And have you added the required permissions in the manifest?

Comment: Will you post whole code

Comment: Dude post manifest too and remove admob id

Comment: added manifest  @Rstar

Comment: logcat gives any information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please review all these additions in your project.

**In Java class:**

```
AdView layout = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView); 
      AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
      //adRequest.setTesting(true);              
      layout.loadAd(adRequest);
```

**In Layout:**

```
<LinearLayout        
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads">

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="your key" />
</LinearLayout>
```

*In Manifest:*

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" 
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" />
```

I have worked with **AdMob Lib. Ver. 4.0.4** which worked fine in my case.

Comment: adMob is available from android 3.2

Comment: @Rstar : Yah, its also available in the `extras` folder within `SDK`, but it showed library errors and it didn't worked in my case so I added the info that the above code is compatible with the Admob Library Version 4.0.4.

Comment: @Rstar: Yes, you do. My old display name was Haps. We usually meet in Android People and help each other.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(),
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()+getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()-50);
AdView ad = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "admob_id");
adParams.addView(ad);
AdRequest r = new AdRequest();
//r.setTesting(true);
ad.loadAd(r);
```

Comment: @Pratik Butan Just comment it.

Comment: Now then also working... why??? and when i upload my apk then it must me comment, right?

Comment: @Pratik Butan You can remove it . no matter

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you included correct ID and have correspond permissions for your app.

In addition it would be good to implement ADListener that really displays what how its going with ads rendering.

Also don't forget to set test mode to query ads, AdMob guys can just ban you for irresponsible clicks.

Answer (score 0):

for latest Ads in Android

use below code

```
   AdView layout = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .build();
    //adRequest.setTesting(true);
    layout.loadAd(adRequest);
```

beacuse AdRequest class final class so we can not create object.